# Unit test cases for Core Data queries

Tags: swift, unit-testing, core-data

I have an application using Core Data as its database, I'm trying to write test cases for my DB queries which I have written inside my `NSManagedObject` subclass and they will return true if the insertion works successfully. I'm trying to insert an object into my entity like this:

```
func testDBInser() {
    let appDelegate: AppDelegate = AppDelegate()
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let myObject: MyManagedObject =  MyManagedObject(context: managedObjectContext)
    myObject.id = 10
    myObject.name = "testObj"
    XCTAssertTrue(UserProfileModel().insertObjectToUserProfile(myObject))
}
```

But I'm getting this error for my test:
An NSManagedObject may only be in (or observed by) a single NSManagedObjectContext

Comment: What is the code `UserProfileModel().insertObjectToUserProfile(myObject)` doing? Are you accessing a second context and checking for the object before saving?

Comment: @richardpiazza I have added an extension to my nsmanagedObject class and wrote queries handeling there, it takes an managedObject and insert it to my entity

Answer (score 0):

Life is a lot easier with [CoreStore](https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore):

```
func testInsert {
    // 1. Arrange
    let dataStack: DataStack = {
        let dataStack = DataStack(xcodeModelName: "ModelName")
        do {
            try dataStack.addStorageAndWait()
        } catch let error {
            XCTFail("Cannot set up database storage: \(error)")
        }
        return dataStack
    }()

    // 2. Action
    do {
        try dataStack.perform(synchronous: { transaction in
            let object = transaction.create(Into<TestObject>())
            object.name = "Test"
        })
    } catch let error {
        XCTFail("Cannot perform database transaction: \(error)")
    }

    // 3. Assert
    do {
        try dataStack.perform(synchronous: { transaction in
            guard transaction.fetchOne(From<TestObject>(), Where("name", isEqualTo: "Test")) != nil else {
                XCTFail("Cannot get database object")
            }
        })
    } catch let error {
        XCTFail("Cannot perform database transaction: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply
please read post comments so you will understand that I want to call methods from my own class which fails.

Comment: With same code, I failed on From.swift -> applyToFetchRequest